# Creating sequence in query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to add an incremental column to tally time in 30 second increments for a report and need to add said column to an existing query but cannot find a way to add it without rebuilding the report and I don't have that kind of time.

Using identity and sequence just give me an error because I am using an open query table generated from a Wonderware Historian query and querying that table. Now I need to add a column that puts a 30 second increment per line starting at zero for line one.

Sorry if I am wording this terribly I'm unsure how else to ask. Can anyone help me with some code to add a generated incremental INT column to a query without having to make a bunch of extra tables with joins?

Comment: can you increment by 30 with row number?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(.....) * 30`?

Comment: I need it to start at 0 otherwise that would work

Comment: jeez...`(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(....) - 1)*30`

Comment: i added a -30 onto that and it worked lol

Comment: sorry for being a pain I'm just really new to SQL still and didn't think about that because i thought the syntax was stricter